# What's the best way to have a colored shadow that wraps around any-shaped layout/view?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I've been struggling with shadows in Android for awhile.
So far, I ended up using https://github.com/L-Briand/ShadowLayout most of the time.
Although it works fine for static views of any shape, it bugs a lot in any animation.

[image]

I'm looking for a better or easier way. Any suggestions?

My UIs have lot of irregular shapes (not just rounded rectangles) also it has to be at least 26+ (even if the app is 21+, I think it be ok with a lesser alternative for 26-). So, to sum up, what I'm looking for is a library or way of having a shadow:

- Can wrap around any shaped layout
- It's not a multilayer drawable
- Can be animated
- Can be colored
- At least 26+

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

I'll pick the best answer in a week (I think that's fair).

Comment: Requests for libraries are off topic here.

Comment: I'm not requesting for someone to make a library... I'm requesting knowledge, how's that off topic? Isn't that the whole point of StackOverflow?

Comment: I get that you're not asking us to code for you.  I'm not trying to flame you.  But this is literally an enumerated reason to close a question-  requesting outside resources or software libraries.  The point of SO isn't to share any programming knowledge, its to be a repository of questions and answers to software problems, with the idea of helping people with an answer for years.  Libraries are a bad fit for that because they change, get canceled, and new ones are added all the time.  (Its legit to answer a question with a library, but not to ask for one).

Comment: If your question could be reworded into a "How can I do this" and someone answers with a library that's cool-  but I think you'd need to add details about what you're trying to do with shadows to get there.

Comment: You don't see the shadows? :D

Comment: Follow up question in case you update this question to not request a library: what does “must be 26+” mean? Do you mean the opposite, that it doesn’t have to work on API’s lower than 26? Because it literally means that you will not accept a solution that would work on earlier levels which doesn’t make sense.

Comment: Thank you, I meant it must support API 26 at least.